# WebView control in xamarin not rendering HTML ionicons in iOS device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Our xamarin mobile application in iOS we have a contentpage, which has a webview Control that loads the HTML data.

The HTML data is rendered properly but the icons are not visible, the icons are ionicons which are used from css files.

The same control and code working without any issues in Android devices and the issue happens only on iOS.

I have tired with multiple approaches but still nothing helped.

Code:
In Xaml File:

```
 <StackLayout>
            <WebView  x:Name="webviewHelp" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></WebView>
        </StackLayout>
```

In Xaml.cs file

```
            var urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource();
            string baseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().GetBaseUrl();
            string filePathUrl = baseUrl;
            urlSource.Url = filePathUrl;
            webviewHelp.Source = urlSource;
```

Here WebView Control we added UrlWebViewSource to point out the html file to render and load. Does anything need to be changed in code to make the icons load while viewing html files in ios?

NOTE: The same code and process working in Android.